# How get started "supporting my project on this site"

Tags: discussion

I posted previously at Chemistry.meta.SE: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/. Same question, but I'll be a little more brief, because I get the sense that this is, in fact the right venue.

I'm the lead developer of an open source Python library for path sampling simulations. As my userbase has grown, I get more and more emails with usage questions. I'm always happy to answer those questions, but I'd rather do so somewhere that is searchable for the rest of the world. So I'm hoping to do what's described at https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/product-support.

Before I start directing users to Matter Modeling:

1. Is this the right forum for it? (I feel much more confident of that here than at Chemistry.SE.)
2. In terms of getting started, of course our code doesn't have a tag here yet (in fact, there isn't a tag here yet for the broader field of "rare events"). So I thought I could recommend users come here and tag their questions about my software with "molecular-dynamics" and "software" or "software-assistance". Is that the way to do it, or is there another suggestion?

Comment: Interesting program, I've never heard of it. Could we chat in a chat room? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113915/protein-folding-docking-and-biomatter-modeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is this the tag you're looking for?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/tags/openpathsampling/info)

Comment: That is indeed! Now I need to update our website and ask the users I whose emails I was just replying to if they'd repeat their question here.

Comment: Once some of them have used that tag, then we can remove the tag from the question it's on right now, because I added it there just to create the tag! But if a tag has no questions it gets deleted by the system (we have no control over that). You can also suggest them to use tags such as molecular-dynamics. software-assistance is more about if software is not working the way it's expected an a developer or power user needs to see it. Questions can have up to 5 tags. We can make rare-events and path-sampling but only if they're likely to be used enough, otherwise it's more useful to add others.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for everyone on the site, but I think this sort of software support is one of the main reasons this site was created. There is a wide variety of matter modeling codes/software and unfortunately a lot of the information about them is spread around dozens of different forums of various quality/openness. Having an SE site offers the benefits of making questions easily searchable and allowing for "software agnostic" questions where a user knows *what* they want to do, but doesn't necessarily know *what program(s)* can do it.

So I would say this would definitely be the right place for these questions. As Nike mentioned, tagging here tends to work on an "as needed" basis, so we can add appropriate tags for your software and related topics as we start to see more of these sorts of questions.